# python-polars is there a np.where equivalent?

Tags: python-polars

Polars is there a np.where equivalent? trying to replicate the following code in polars.
If the value is above a certain threshold column called Is_Acceptable is 1 or if it is below it is 0

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({"fruit":["orange","apple","mango","kiwi"], "value":[1,0.8,0.7,1.2]})
df["Is_Acceptable?"] = np.where(df["value"].lt(0.9), 1, 0)
print(df)
```

Comment: You can use [polars.when](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.when.html?highlight=when) expression

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is `pl.when().then().otherwise()` expression

```
import polars as pl
from polars import col

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "fruit": ["orange","apple","mango","kiwi"],
    "value": [1, 0.8, 0.7, 1.2]
})

df = df.with_column(
    pl.when(col('value') < 0.9).then(1).otherwise(0).alias('Is_Acceptable?')
)
print(df)

┌────────┬───────┬────────────────┐
│ fruit  ┆ value ┆ Is_Acceptable? │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---            │
│ str    ┆ f64   ┆ i64            │
╞════════╪═══════╪════════════════╡
│ orange ┆ 1.0   ┆ 0              │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ apple  ┆ 0.8   ┆ 1              │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ mango  ┆ 0.7   ┆ 1              │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ kiwi   ┆ 1.2   ┆ 0              │
└────────┴───────┴────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 4):

The `when/then/otherwise` expression is a good general-purpose answer.  However, in this case, one shortcut is to simply create a boolean expression.

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        (pl.col('value') < 0.9).alias('Is_Acceptable')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬───────┬───────────────┐
│ fruit  ┆ value ┆ Is_Acceptable │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---           │
│ str    ┆ f64   ┆ bool          │
╞════════╪═══════╪═══════════════╡
│ orange ┆ 1.0   ┆ false         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ apple  ┆ 0.8   ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ mango  ┆ 0.7   ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ kiwi   ┆ 1.2   ┆ false         │
└────────┴───────┴───────────────┘
```

In numeric computations, `False` will be upcast to `0`, and `True` will be upcast to `1`.  Or, if you prefer, you can upcast them explicitly to a different type.

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        (pl.col('value') < 0.9).cast(pl.Int64).alias('Is_Acceptable')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬───────┬───────────────┐
│ fruit  ┆ value ┆ Is_Acceptable │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---           │
│ str    ┆ f64   ┆ i64           │
╞════════╪═══════╪═══════════════╡
│ orange ┆ 1.0   ┆ 0             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ apple  ┆ 0.8   ┆ 1             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ mango  ┆ 0.7   ┆ 1             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ kiwi   ┆ 1.2   ┆ 0             │
└────────┴───────┴───────────────┘
```